# CKEditor russian spell check

Tags: internationalization, ckeditor, spell-checking

How to add Russian spell check for CKEditor or enable Firefox default spell checker?

In FCKeditor, method `FCKConfig.FirefoxSpellChecker = true;` work, but in CKEditor the method is not longer available.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.disableNativeSpellChecker

> Disables the built-in spell checker while typing natively available in the browser (currently Firefox and Safari only).
>
> Even if word suggestions will not appear in the CKEditor context menu, this feature is useful to help quickly identifying misspelled words.
>
> This setting is currently compatible with Firefox only due to limitations in other browsers.
> Defined in: plugins/wysiwygarea/plugin.js.

`config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Disables the auto-check spelling plugin *scayt*:

```
config.scayt_autoStartup = false;
```

Disables the ban on standard spell checking by browser:

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
```

Disables the named *scayt* plugin and prohibits to replace the context menu:

```
config.removePlugins = 'scayt';
```

Hide button:

```
config.removeButtons = 'Scayt';
```

Comment: It requires extra steps to remove context menu in later versions of ckeditor, this worked for me:

config.removePlugins = 'liststyle,tabletools,scayt,menubutton,contextmenu';

http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Disable-context-menu